# Exception "Out of Memory" in EF

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, out-of-memory, edmx

For retrieving data with some criteria from the database, I use this code:

```
IEnumerable<Object> iEnumuDeclarations2 = ObjectDAO.Find(d => d.id == 1).ToList();
```

but it is too slow. And at the end an exception out of memory occurs

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate)
{
    return DataContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>().Where<TEntity>(predicate);
}
```

Comment: It really depends on your schema but is it possible that you have a circular dependency among your entities?

Comment: concerning the tables I'm requestiong or the whole  schema ?

Comment: What does ``at least an exception out of memory occures``, specially the part ``at least`` ?

Comment: at last not at least

Comment: You should use ``Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>`` instead of ``Func<TEntity, bool>``

Comment: and what is the difference ?

Comment: The difference is, the expression can be interpreted by EF to generate an SQL query, and execute it on the mssql server, what you are doing essentialy is getting every single object into memory and then query the local objects, depending on the size of your database it could result in out of memory exception but still unlikely. But atleast this explains the slowness.

Comment: Did as you asked me to do, just for future dont forget to write @username when you want the attention of a user. Without it I dont get a notification and therefor didnt know you answered to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>` instead of `Func<TEntity, bool>`

The difference is, the expression can be interpreted by EF to generate an SQL query, and execute it on the mssql server, what you are doing essentialy is getting every single object into memory and then query the local objects, depending on the size of your database it could result in out of memory exception but still unlikely. But atleast this explains the slowness.

Answer (score 1):

please try this may be it is working :

```
var iEnumuDeclarations2  = declaration_importationDAO.Where(d => d.id_service == id_service).ToList();
```

Comment: The .find method is calling the .where

Comment: The point is that find starts by searching in the local cache of the context and then, if no match, sends a query to the DB.

where always sends a query to the DB.